# T-SQL create multiply records from one records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a cost record and I would like to create N records from it.
The children records have some different parameters.
For example:

The parents record:

```
date     |  amount | duration
20170201 | 5000    | 5 months
```

The children records:

```
date     |  amount | duration
20170301 |  1000   | 1 months 
20170401 |  1000   | 1 months 
20170501 |  1000   | 1 months
20170601 |  1000   | 1 months
20170701 |  1000   | 1 months
```

How can I do this without iteration? Without cursor or while?

Comment: Is duration only in months as time unit or is it changing as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following SQL CTE query could be used based on Abdul's solution

```
/*
Create Table PARENT (PARENT_DATE DATE, PARENT_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),PARENT_MONTH INT)
INSERT INTO PARENT SELECT '20170201',5000 ,5
INSERT INTO PARENT SELECT '20180601',120 ,3
*/
;WITH CTE_CHILD
AS  (

    SELECT
        Parent_Date,
        Parent_Amount,
        Parent_Month,
        DateAdd(Month, 1, Parent_Date) as Child_Date,
        Parent_Amount/Parent_Month  AS Child_Amount,
        1 AS Child_Duration
    FROM Parent

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Parent_Date,
        Parent_Amount,
        Parent_Month,
        DateAdd(Month, 1, Child_Date) as Child_Date,
        Child_Amount,
        Child_Duration
    FROM CTE_CHILD
    WHERE 
        DateAdd(Month, 1, Child_Date) <= DateAdd(Month, Parent_Month, Parent_Date)

)
SELECT
    Child_Date,
    Child_Amount,
    Child_Duration
 FROM CTE_CHILD
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a table like below:

```
create table tblRecords ( date int, amount money, duration int);
insert into tblRecords values
(20170201,5000,5),
(20180101,9000,3);
```

you can use a query like below:

```
select  
    date= date + r*100
    ,amount= amount/duration
    ,duration =1 
from tblRecords
cross apply
(
    select top  (select duration)
    r= row_number() over(order by (select null))
    from 
    sys.objects s1 
    cross join 
    sys.objects s2
) h
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/OXBUNJ57172)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One method is `CTE`.

```
DECLARE @PARENT AS TABLE
    (PARENT_DATE DATE, PARENT_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),PARENT_MONTH INT)
INSERT INTO @PARENT
SELECT '20170201',5000 ,5

;WITH CTE_CHILD
AS  (
    SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH,1,PARENT_DATE) AS CHILD_DATE
            ,PARENT_AMOUNT/PARENT_MONTH  AS CHILD_AMOUNT
            ,1                           AS CHILD_DURATION
    FROM    @PARENT
    WHERE   DATEADD(MONTH,1,PARENT_DATE) <= DATEADD(MONTH,PARENT_MONTH,PARENT_DATE)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH,1,CHILD_DATE)
            ,PARENT_AMOUNT/PARENT_MONTH
            ,1
    FROM    CTE_CHILD
    INNER JOIN @PARENT ON DATEADD(MONTH,1,CHILD_DATE) <= DATEADD(MONTH,PARENT_MONTH,PARENT_DATE)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_CHILD 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Output:-

```
CHILD_DATE  CHILD_AMOUNT        CHILD_DURATION
2017-03-01  1000.0000000000000  1
2017-04-01  1000.0000000000000  1
2017-05-01  1000.0000000000000  1
2017-06-01  1000.0000000000000  1
2017-07-01  1000.0000000000000  1
```

Comment: If there are more than one rows in the Parent table, the query produces many rows than expected unfortunately

Comment: @Eralper, that time, need to filter the parent row in the first query of the CTE uisng a WHERE clause and/or restrict the JOIN in second query.

Comment: Please check my solution, I did not use a filtering criteria in anchor part of the CTE

Comment: @Eralper,+1 for the same